# Adjust cover picture according to user wish-CSS

Tags: php, css

I have to set cover picture having width:1025px and height:392px. First i set like this and get the stretched result, then i changed the image within div and add this property (Background-size:cover). This gives good result. But i want it like facebook cover photo, in that we can adjust and fix our cover photo according to our wish. Here is my code...

**CSS**

```
 .container{
 background-size: cover;
 background-image: url(images/uploadcover/$cimg);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 width:auto;
 height:392px;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container"></div>
```

If any idea suggest me.

Comment: you will be needing heavy jquery/javascript for that.. not possible with plain css.

Comment: I have found by this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UAgDA/35/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's that fiddle
`$(function(){
     $(".headerima ge").css('cursor','s-resize'); 
     var y1 = $('.picturecontainer').height(); 
     var y2 = $('.headerimage').height(); 
     $(".headerimage").draggable({ 
                                   scroll: false, 
                                   axis: "y", 
                                   drag: function(event, ui) { 
                                       if(ui.position.top >= 0) 
                                       { 
                                           ui.position.top = 0; 
                                       } 
                                       else if(ui.position.top <= y1 - y2) 
                                       { 
                                           ui.position.top = y1 - y2; 
                                       } 
   }, 
   stop: function(event, ui) { 
             //#### 
 } 
         });  
                   });`